# Why shouldn't I hold onto debt funds for a long term?

Tags: india, mutual-funds

(I'm in India) I've heard that debt funds should ideally be redeemed in 3 to 5 years. If the money is to be invested for a longer duration, equity funds are to be used.
Is that valid? If so, why?

I always like to think of debt funds as hedge against equities; i.e. whenever there's a slump in the equity funds, the debt funds will automatically rise by approximately the same amount, and vice-versa. But this window of 3-5 years makes me wonder whether I am missing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both strategies are legitimate:

- If you must have all the money back in 3-5 years (e.g. for a planned expenditure), then equities would be too risky. They could crash right before your planned expenditure
- If you wish to diversify or hedge, then bonds/loans could be a permanent holding